# Ignore OnRowCommand in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, updatepanel

I want the click event of a `LinkButton` in my `GridView` to **not** call the grid view's `OnRowCommand` event.

The reason is because I want to encapsulate this in an `UpdatePanel` and update `ErrorUpdateTextBox` without performing a postback.

```
<asp:GridView ID="DataSourceMappingGridView" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Index" ClientIDMode="Static" OnRowCommand="DataSourceMappingGridView_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="DataSourceMappingGridView_RowDataBound">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="ErrorUpdatePanel" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>          
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="ErrorTextLinkButton" runat="server" Text='View Errors'  OnClick="ErrorTextLinkButton_Click" /> 
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ErrorUpdateTextBox" runat="server" Text="">
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to avoid a post back (`UpdatePanel`s still do a partial post back), then I would recommend capturing the link button's click event client-side and then doing an AJAX call to the server to save/get whatever data is relevant to the link button being clicked, like this:

Remove the `OnClick` attribute (leave the `runat="server"` attribute so you can add the ID value to the link button during binding) and add a `class` attribute to the `LinkButton` markup to allow jQuery to easily wire up a click event handler, like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="ErrorTextLinkButton" runat="server" Text='View Errors' 
                class="error" /> 

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.error').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "PageName.aspx/GetError",
            data: "{'id':'7'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                // Do something error data returned here
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Finally, create an ASP.NET AJAX Page Method, like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetError(int id)
{
    // Go and get error data from database or service, etc.
    return "Your error message here";
}
```